# How can i know when an Application.exe is running and when is closed in VB.Net?

Tags: windows, vb.net, cmd, process

I am currently developing an application that opens a program.exe with a login, but I need to know when that application closes. Maybe I will monitor the process of that program, but I don't know how to do it.

How can I know when an application is running and know when they close it?

Comment: You can set [Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents) and subscribe to [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited) event. If the Process has a Window, you can also use UI Automation, setting up a [WindowPattern.WindowClosedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowclosedevent)

Comment: *If the Process has a Window* also means a Console Window.

Comment: Personally, I would tend to consider calling `WaitForExit` if the process will exit very quickly, testing `HasExited` if it will exit quite quickly and handling `Exited` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
Dim proc = Process.Start("full path of your exe here")
proc.WaitForExit()
```

First row runs the application, whie the second waits for the app to finish.

Or, if you want a continous check

```
Private Async Sub RunExeAndWait()
    Dim proc = Process.Start("full path of your exe here")

    While Not proc.HasExited
        Await Task.Delay(1000)
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check `Process.HasExited`

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim p = Process.Start("notepad.exe")

    While Not p.HasExited
        Await Task.Delay(100)
    End While

    MessageBox.Show("Closed")
End Sub
```

Comment: You beat me for the `HasExited` part, +1 for you!

Comment: @Marco History will tell a different tale, because you edited so quickly :)